# Android Outofmemory error, external memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I created an emulator with **Android 2.2** kernel and max VM heap size =`24Mb`. When an activity runs on it, the logcat show outofmemory error:

```
"861984-byte external allocation too larger for this process"
```

Can I know what does *"external allocation"* here mean? Is this the *"external memory"*? This activity call `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.

The layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
>
<ImageView  
android:layout_width="190dp" 
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:scaleType = "fitXY"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/login_btn_fb"
android:id="@+id/facebookconnect"/>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:visibility = "visible"
android:src="@drawable/splash"
android:scaleType = "fitXY"
android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The dimension of image *splash.png* is `640*960`

Before **Honeycomb**, pixel data of image was stored in *"native memory"*. Is *"native memory"* the same as *"external memory"*?

Comment: I think you are using bitmap class and bitmapfactory class objects to showing the image in an imageview.? right?

Comment: No. I just use setContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: you are trying to load the more than one picture in an imageview.right? Could u post ur code.? you must free the object of imageview,each time you load the new image.

Comment: increase the heap size by editing the AVD.

Answer (score 3):

set your imageview to null each time when you load the new image.Or use recycle() method to your imageview object each time when you load the new image

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html). I solved my memory issue in the `setContentView` call by creating my own theme (using a tiled drawable) rather than using a default Android theme then setting a large image as background that caused redrawing of the layout which is wasteful to both memory and CPU performance.